# No Pidgin main window on First Open

Tags: window, pidgin

I removed emapathy and installed pidgin. Why ? because i hate empathy.

The problem is that when i start pidgin for first time after login into ubuntu. via dash or me menu, i cannot see the main window.

An icon pops up both in launcher and even in the alt+tab window switcher thing.
but no main window preview even on pressing alt + ` or clicking on the launcher..

i have to right click on it launcher in dash, quit it and den again open pidgin to see the main chat window.

i don't know whats the issue here but its very irritating.

Comment: Thank you for posting at Askubuntu. Although bugs should be reported at http://launchpad.net. See http://askubuntu.com/faq and <a href="http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug">How Do I Report A Bug</a>

Comment: Here's the bug ticket: http://goo.gl/i8y33

Comment: [Full bug link to Launchpad bug #1001405](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1001405), for those of us who don't like clicking on mysterious shortlinks. :)