# Sometimes invisible Pidgin

Tags: pidgin

I have MSN, XMPP, SIPE (with plugin) and Skype (with plugin) in my Pidgin configured. If I open Pidgin through Unity launcher, Unity menu or with autostart sometimes the Pidgin main contact window is hidden. If someone writes a message, the message window appears. Only by killing the task with "kill -9 ****" helps and brings the window back to desktop by restart of Pidgin. Only closing Pidgin and starting Pidgin again doesn't work.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pidgin is not fully Unity compliant. I had the same issue: [pidgin-not-showing-up-after-opening-it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78854/pidgin-not-showing-up-after-opening-it)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had found a trick before, that before shutdown I left the Pidgin contacts window open. The next time, I didn’t experience any problem in opening Pidgin contacts list.

But recently I think I’ve found kind of a solution and I just want to share.

Go to **Preferences -> Interface**, and put **System Tray Icon** on **Always**.

In fact, this is not a solution and you may still face the problem, but after this setting you *don’t* need to *quit* Pidgin to solve the problem.

---

**My testing results in detail**

Pidgin may be locked to the launcer or not:

1. Locked to the launcher: the contacts list is shown by one click after restart and no problem. After a logout and login again, Pidgin will be active by one click and all its functions will work; for example, you can change the status from the messaging menu, but to see contacts list you should click the icon *again*.
2. Not locked: you should make it active one time, for example through messaging menu; and click again to see the contacts list.

Anyway, no need to quit Pidgin and run it again – as I mentioned. So I recommend to users to follow this setting.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, you can at least automate the client-bouncing procedure with a script. ^_^

```
#/bin/bash
kill $(ps ax | grep -m 1 pidgin | awk {'print $1'})
pidgin &
```